# How to use order by within the STUFF function and exclude specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can I use order by within the STUFF and exclude specific value? Here's my query.

```
SELECT ID, STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + t1.CTY
        FROM country_tbl t1
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS aggregation
FROM master_tbl t2
WHERE t2.ID IN ('123456','123457')
GROUP BY ID;
ORDER BY T2.ID
```

```
t1
ID     Country
123456 England
123457 Canada

t2
ID     CTY
123456 England
123456 Japan
123456 France
123456 Canada
123457 England
123457 Japan
123457 France

Result
ID     CTY
123456 Canada;France;Japan    Except England (CTY Sorted A-Z)    
123457 England;France;Japan   No Exception (CTY Sorted A-Z)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the tag for the RDBMS you're using (there's no STUFF function in standard SQL)

Comment: I've added sql-server tag since I recognize the T-SQL dialect, however you should read the instructions on he [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, this is for MS SQL Server 2016 version...

Comment: Please be aware that `FOR XML PATH('')` was a clever loophole found some time ago that causes all of the rows of output data to be concatenated into a single string. `STUFF(<somestring>,1,1,'')` is just removing the first character from a string. Thinking of the concatenation as being `STUFF` is entirely to get things the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clause in the subquery.  Something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       STUFF( (SELECT ';' + t1.CTY
               FROM country_tbl t1
               WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND
                     NOT (t1.id = '123456' AND t1.CTY = 'England')
               ORDER BY t1.CTY
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) AS aggregation
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM master_tbl t2
      WHERE t2.ID IN ('123456','123457')
     ) t2
ORDER BY T2.ID;
```

I also changed the `GROUP BY` in the outer query to a `SELECT DISTINCT` to boost performance.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to list the cities in t2 except those that appear in t1 with the same ids, in an ascending order.
If that's the case, then you're close, but not quite there.

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @t1 AS TABLE (
    [ID] int, 
    [Country] varchar(7)
);
    
INSERT INTO @t1 ([ID], [Country]) VALUES
(123456, 'England'),
(123457, 'Canada');


DECLARE @t2 AS TABLE (
    [ID] int, 
    [CTY] varchar(7)
);
    
INSERT INTO @t2 ([ID], [CTY]) VALUES
(123456, 'England'),
(123456, 'Japan'),
(123456, 'France'),
(123456, 'Canada'),
(123457, 'England'),
(123457, 'Japan'),
(123457, 'France');
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id,
        STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + t2.CTY
            FROM @t2 As t2
            LEFT JOIN @t1 As t1
                ON t2.Id = t1.Id
                AND t2.CTY = t1.Country
            WHERE t2.ID = t0.ID 
            AND t1.Id IS NULL
            ORDER BY t2.CTY
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS aggregation
FROM @t2 As t0
```

Results:

```
Id      aggregation
123456  Canada;France;Japan
123457  England;France;Japan
```

Comment: Hi Zohar, I got the order by the simplest one STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + t1.CTY
        FROM country_tbl t1
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID order by t1.CTY FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Countries   is there a way to exclude using the same query and using case when t1.Country <> t2.CTY then include else exclude something like that?

Comment: The query I've used already excluded the records from `@t1`. I've based my query on the results you've posted. If my assumptions was incorrect, please edit your question to make it more understandable.